# How to parse usernames from a text file and output results to another text file with batch?

Tags: parsing, batch-file, batch-processing

I am reposting this as someone closed my previous question without time for me to make appropriate edits. I woke up to find it was closed. :C Also, I am new to the site.

I am not sure how to accomplish what I want to do.  I would feel more comfortable using batch. Because, It is a programming language I am more familiar with. Please only batch scripting responses.

I need to parse out the usernames i.e. elocin_anagram LuckeaterVR into a list separated by commas into another text file. The user names are the display names in the string. This string is in a text file named subscriptions_first=100.txt

This is the string:

```
{"_total":19,"subscriptions":[{"created_at":"2018-06-15T19:34:38Z","_id":"b7c42f6ce857162220e99533d3d6dc1ae11fac8d","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡ ♡(elocin_anagram)","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"elocin_anagram","type":"user","bio":"personal bio here.","created_at":"2015-06-17T05:37:38Z","updated_at":"2020-05-11T05:51:58Z","name":"elocin_anagram","_id":"93742615","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d37d128b-59b1-4015-9776-74866feb1d44-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2019-07-10T00:04:45Z","_id":"6a26c5a56b39d142a6e25ad30589a1b923fbc1bb","sub_plan":"1000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub(≧◡≦) ♡ (elocin_anagram) ","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"LuckeaterVR","type":"user","bio":"","created_at":"2018-12-08T04:55:48Z","updated_at":"2020-04-24T01:44:56Z","name":"luckeatervr","_id":"400728304","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/322ba52a-655c-42a4-8cc9-7b875debd5dd-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2020-01-16T01:23:17Z","_id":"17704f74767b5592c5fc221eca11a20579a8162c","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡
```

I need the output of the string in a text file to look like this:

elocin_anagram, LuckeaterVR, username3, username4, username5, ... Username100

The ellipsis (...)  is there to note that there could be 100 usernames in the file.

This will be my first time trying to learn how to parse information from a text file, and outputting it to another text file. I am not sure how to accomplish this, and would really appreciate some guidance, so I can learn. I have tried looking at various tutorials and documentation. None of them have shown me how to get my desired results. In the words of Tom Scott "Once you know the name of a thing, you can google it." Perhaps I am not using the correct search terms. ¯_(ツ)_/¯(shrug)

If there are any issues with this post, please allow me 24 hours for me to fix it before closing it. I have an odd sleeping schedule since quarantine. Also, how do I delete the previous post???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you edit your previous question it will be reopened. But it won't be reopened as it the wrong type of question. See `for /?` for parsing text files in a command prompt. See `set /?` for manipulating variables.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. Are you just making a batch file that sends strings to a text file?

Comment: I think you'll want to use `for /f`.  It seems like you'll want your delimiters to be either commas or semi colons (or probably both).  Then you need to count which token you want from the overall string.  This method *requires* the number of delimiters to be consistent.  This advice might be totally wrong if you have many usernames on a *single* line.  Hopefully you have 1 username per line in your file.

Comment: I don't know json. Can we please stick with batch.

Comment: Your data file is a JSON file.

Comment: So the link https://www.google.com.au/search?q=batchfile+parsing+json#spf=1589235622164 is _how to parse JSON files using **batch file**_.

Comment: Oh sorry mark. Thank you.

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: None of this is working for me. I am not getting the desired results, and still don't know what I am doing wrong. :C

Comment: Can I please get a working example based off the string I have posted. That should be enough to get me somewhere.

Comment: what's is the difference between a tokens and delim?

Comment: Delimiters separate tokens. So `A B C` if space is a delimiter then you have three tokens A, B, and C. If dot is a delimiter, there isn't a dot so you have one token with `A B C` in it. Batch is the worst language to be doing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "file=subscriptions_first=100.txt"
set "output=subscriptions_first=100_display_name.txt"
set "comma="

(    for /f "delims=" %%A in (
        'powershell -noprofile -command
        "$content= get-content -path '%file%' -raw | convertfrom-json;"
        "foreach ($subscription in $content.subscriptions) {"
        "$subscription.user.display_name}"'
    ) do if not defined comma (
        set /p "_=%%~A" <nul
        set "comma=defined"
    ) else (
        set /p "_=, %%~A" <nul
    )
) > "%output%"
```

To get the display_name values, Powershell's `convertfrom-json` can be used.

Environment variable named `file` is set to the path of the text file. Powershell will `get-content` of the file and pipe it to `convertfrom-json`. Access each `user` from the created object to get the value of `display_name`. The echoed display names are redirect to the file specified as set by the environment variable `output`.

Tested with this minimalist json file prettified structure.

> ```
> {
>     "subscriptions": [
>         {
>             "user": {
>                 "display_name": "elocin_anagram"
>             }
>         },
>         {
>             "user": {
>                 "display_name": "LuckeaterVR"
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Output:

> ```
> elocin_anagram, LuckeaterVR
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in batch is not the optimal way, far from it. There are other command line tools that should be used to parse JSON.

Having said that, the following batch file does exactly what you want (according to your input file example) - it is very specific!

Note, however, that since it is a single-line JSON file, it is read into an environment variable as is, and there is a restriction of maximum length for environment variables (I think around 32K - not sure). So if your file is larger than that, it will only parse the first (32K?) characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p JSON_STR=<input_file.json
set display_names=

::call main function with %JSON_sTR% stripped of all quotes
call:get_display_names %JSON_STR:"=%

echo %display_names% > display_names.txt

exit /b

:get_display_names

::exit condition - remove extra ", " from beginning and return
if "%1"=="" set display_names=%display_names:~2% & goto:eof

::get first element (element is anything separated by ,)
set _elem=%1

::if "display_name" is found in _elem, assume it looks like "user:{display_name:NAME_TO_EXTRACT" 
::and get the 19th character and on as the display name, concatenating it to display_names
if not "%_elem:display_name=%"=="%_elem%" set display_names=%display_names%, %_elem:~19%

:: throw away %1 and move %2 to be the new %1 etc.
shift

::continue the loop (we are still inside the single call:get_display_names
goto get_display_names
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, batch isn't the best solution (maybe even one of the worst) for this task, but it's not completely powerless. The first `for` loop splits the string into single elements (split by default delimiters like SPACE, TAB, COMMA), the second `for` filters for the desired elements and extracts the correct part:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "string={"_total":19,"subscriptions":[{"created_at":"2018-06-15T19:34:38Z","_id":"b7c42f6ce857162220e99533d3d6dc1ae11fac8d","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡ ♡(elocin_anagram)","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"elocin_anagram","type":"user","bio":"personal bio here.","created_at":"2015-06-17T05:37:38Z","updated_at":"2020-05-11T05:51:58Z","name":"elocin_anagram","_id":"93742615","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d37d128b-59b1-4015-9776-74866feb1d44-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2019-07-10T00:04:45Z","_id":"6a26c5a56b39d142a6e25ad30589a1b923fbc1bb","sub_plan":"1000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub(≧◡≦) ♡ (elocin_anagram) ","is_gift":false,"user":{"display_name":"LuckeaterVR","type":"user","bio":"","created_at":"2018-12-08T04:55:48Z","updated_at":"2020-04-24T01:44:56Z","name":"luckeatervr","_id":"400728304","logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/322ba52a-655c-42a4-8cc9-7b875debd5dd-profile_image-300x300.png"},"sender":null},{"created_at":"2020-01-16T01:23:17Z","_id":"17704f74767b5592c5fc221eca11a20579a8162c","sub_plan":"3000","sub_plan_name":"Channel Sub (❤ω❤)♡ ♡ "

for %%a in (!string!) do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%b in ('echo %%a^|find "display_name"') do (
    echo found %%~b
    set "users=!users!, %%~b"
  )
)
echo %users:~2
```

NOTE: this works for your example string. But there is a line length limit, which you may hit when there are more users (you spoke of "100")